Trying to implement a function to visualize the decision boundaries and I get ValueError: 'red' is not a valid color value
I am trying to use a perceptron in the Iris data set and implement a function to visualize the decision boundaries but I get this:

ValueError: 'red' is not a valid color value.

I also tried using color codes.
Here's my code:
  import numpy as np 

    class Perceptron:
    """ Perceptron classifier
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    
    eta:float
        Learning rate(between 0.0 and 1.0)
    n_iter:int
        Passes over the training data set
    random_state:int
        Random generator sedd for random weight
        initialization.
        
    Attributes
    ----------
    
    W_:1-darray
        Weights after fitting
    b_:Scalar
        Bias unit after fitting
        
    errors_: list
        Number of misclassifications(updates) in each epoch.
        
    """
    
    def __init__(self, eta=0.01, n_iter=50, random_state=1):
        self.eta = eta
        self.n_iter= n_iter
        self.random_state=random_state
        
    def fit(self,X,Y):
        """ Fit training data.
        
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        
        X: {array-like}, shape = [n_examples, n_features]
         Training vectors, where n_examples is the number of examples and n_features is the number of          features.
        y : array-like, shape = [n_examples]
          Target values.
          
        Returns
        -------
        self: object
        
        """
        
        rgen=np.random.RandomState(self.random_state)
        self.w_ = rgen.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.01,
                               size=X.shape[1])
        self.b_=np.float_(0.)
        self.errors_ = []
        
        for _ in range(self.n_iter):
            errors=0
            for xi, target in zip(X, y):
                update=self.eta * (target - self.predict(xi))
                self.w_ += update * xi
                self.b_ += update
                errors += int(update != 0.0)
            self.errors_.append(errors)
        
        return self
    
    def net_input(self, X):
        """ Calculate net output """
        return np.dot(X, self.w_) + self.b_
    
    def predict(self, X):
        """ Return class label after unit step """
        return np.where(self.net_input(X) >= 0.0, 1, 0)

#Training on Iris dataset

import pandas as pd 
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
s=' https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data '

df=pd.read_csv(s,header= None )
df.tail()


#select Setosa and versicolor

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

y=df.iloc[0:100, 4].values
y=np.where(y=='Iris-setosa',0,1)

#extract sepal lenght and petal lenght

X=df.iloc[0:100,[0,2]].values
#plot data
plt.scatter(X[:50,0],X[:50,1],
        color='red', marker='o', label ='Setosa')
plt.scatter(X[50:100,0],X[50:100,1],
        color='blue', marker ='s', label='Versicolor')
plt.xlabel('Sepal lenght[cm]')
plt.ylabel('Petal lenght[cm]')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

 the distribution of flower examples
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap



from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, resolution=0.02 ):
    #setup marker generator and color map
    markers=('o', 's', '^', 'v', '<')
    colors = ('#FF0000', '#0000FF', '#90EE90', '#808080', '#00FFFF')
    cmap= ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])

    #plot the decision surface
    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min()-1,X[:,0].max()+1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:,1].min()-1, X[:, 1].max()+1
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x2_max, resolution),
                       np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    lab=classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    lab=lab.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, lab, alpha=0.3, cmap=cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())

    #plot class exmples 
    for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
        plt.scatter(x=X[y==cl, 0],
                    y=X[y==cl, 1],
                    alpha=0.8,
                    c=colors[idx],
                    marker=markers[idx],
                    label=f'Class{cl}',
                    edgecolor='black')

And finally
plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier=ppn)
plt.xlabel('Sepal lenght[cm]')
plt.ylabel('Petal lenght[cm]')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

